# LeVeque excercise Total Variation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, total-variation

In Randall LeVeque Finite Volume Methods I've come across the Exercise 6.2 and 6.4.

> **6.2** Compute the total variation of
> a). $$q(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1&\text{if }x<0\\\sin(\pi x)&\text{if } 0\leq x\leq 3\\2 &\text{if }x>3\end{array}\right.$$

Here with the definition $TV(q)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|q^\prime(x)|dx$ I get $0$ since $\int_0^3\pi\cos(\pi x)=0.$

> b). $$q(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}1&\text{if }x<0&\text{or }x=3\\1&\text{if }0\leq x\leq 1&\text{or } 2\leq x<3\\-1&\text{if }1<x<2\\2&\text{if }x>3\end{array}\right.$$

Here the solution is also $0$. But both do not feel right...

> **6.4** Show that $TV(Q^{n+1}) \leq TV(q^n(\cdot, t_{n+1}))$ is valid by showing that, for any function $q(x)$, if we define discrete values $Q_i$ by averaging $q(x)$ over grid cells, then $TV(Q) \leq TV(q)$.

> Hint: Use the definition $TV(q) = sup\sum_{j=1}^n|q(\xi_j) − q(\xi_{j−1})|$, and the fact that the average value of $q$ lies between the maximum
> and minimum values on each grid cell.

The definition for $TV$ is $TV(Q_i) =\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}|Q_i−Q_{i−1}|$. But how does this leads to the hint and then to the solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For 6.2 (a), you need to compute $\int_0^3|\pi \cos(\pi x)|\, dx$. When you use the absolute values, you should find that the answer is greater than $0$.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Oh, I see... So the solution is 6? And what about (b)?

Comment: With the definition from 6.4 the solution to 6.2 (b) should be 5. Is this true?